# Submitting to Apple App Store: Specify brand name as individual developer?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I did register as an individual developer with Apple.

However, I'd prefer not to have my real name below the App name in the App Store but a 'brand' name.

Is it possible to specify such a name when submitting the App to the App Store? If not, is there any other way beside re-registering as a company (I do not have a company nor would I like to file all the possible paperwork).

I've read people asking similar questions after submitting their app, I thought I could avoid the trouble in foresight.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Note: The company name defaults to the legal entity name you enter
>   when you enroll in the Apple Developer Program. If you enroll as a
>   company, you can set the company name (distinct from your legal entity
>   name) only once when you add your first app, as described in Creating
>   an iTunes Connect Record for an App. The company name must be a
>   registered DBA or trade name. The company name will be used for all
>   your apps and can’t be changed later. **If you enroll as an individual,
>   the company name is the same as your legal name.** In the store, the
>   “company name” is used prominently for navigation and to group your
>   apps. Your legal entity name appears as the “seller” of your apps. For
>   example, “Apple” is the company name and “Apple, Inc” is the seller
>   name. When users tap your company name, they see all of the apps you
>   have on the store.

If you have registered as an individual, according to the guidelines, the only valid option is your legal name.
This also makes a lot of sense, because if you add some fancy name and someone owns the *copyrights* to that name; both  you and iTunes will face a lot of needless legal mess.

So for now you can proceed with your individual account, with your name set as the the brand name. And in the future if you happen to register a company, simply create a new iTunes company account and have your App transferred to that account.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW1